# How to form two arrays from string separated by "," and followed by -?

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string

```
$str="a,b,c,d-e,f,g,h"
```

I am trying to extract the strings from `$str` that are separated "," and are before "-" in one array and the strings separated by "," and are after "-" in second array. So that `$arr1=array(a,b,c,d);` and `$arr2=array(e,f,g,h);`. I am just using `$str` as an example and generally I want this to work for any string of the same form i.e. `$str=s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,....-r1,r2,t3....`

NOTE: If `$str` doesn't have "-" then `$arr2` vanishes and `$arr1` contains an array of the elements separated by ',' in `$str`.

This is what I tried

```
preg_match_all('~(^|.*,)(.*)(,.*|\-|$)~', $str, $arr1);
preg_match_all('~(-|.*,)(.*)(,.*|$)~', $str, $arr2);
```

However each array comes with one element that contains the  string `str`.
Does anyone know why this is not working.

Comment: Have a look at [this code](https://ideone.com/c3Klft) - is it what you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(.*?(?=-|$))|(?<=-)(.*$)
```

You can use this to get `2` arrays.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vV1wW6/19

Your regex is not working as you have used `greedy` modifier.`.*,` will stop at the last instance of `,`

EDIT:

Use this is you want string after `-` to be in second group.

```
^(.*?(?=-|$))(?:-(.*$))?
```

https://regex101.com/r/vV1wW6/20

Comment: This does not work with a string of the form `'-a,b,c,d'`. The element `a`,`b`,`c`,`d` are extracted in `$arr1` not `$arr2`

Answer (score 3):

All of your regex patterns are not optimal and it seems the task is easier to solve with [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

> `array_map()` returns an array containing all the elements of `array1` after applying the callback function to each one. The number of parameters that the callback function accepts should match the number of arrays passed to the `array_map()`

```
$str="a,b,c,d-e,f,g,h";
$ex = array_map(function ($s) {
       return explode(",", $s);
    }, explode("-", $str));
print_r($ex);
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/c3Klft)

Results:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
            [2] => c
            [3] => d
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => e
            [1] => f
            [2] => g
            [3] => h
        )

)
```

Comment: If you have any doubts, please feel free to drop a comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `preg_match` to check does your string contains `-` if yes than can simply use `array_walk` like as

```
$str = 'a,b,c,d-e,f,g,h';
$result = [];
if(preg_match('/[-]/', $str)){
    array_walk(explode('-',$str),function($v,$k)use(&$result){
        $result[] = explode(',',$v);
    });
}else{
    array_walk(explode(',',$str),function($v,$k)use(&$result){
        $result[] = $v;
    });
}
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Downvoters atleast post the reason behind downvoting. So I can improve my answer

Answer (score 0):

Without regex (the most reasonable way):

```
$str="a,b,c,d-e,f,g,h";

list($arr1, $arr2) = explode('-', $str);

$arr1 = explode(',', $arr1);

if ($arr2)
    $arr2 = explode(',', $arr2);
else
    unset($arr2);
```

With regex (for the challenge):

```
if (preg_match_all('~(?:(?!\G)|\A)([^-,]+)|-?([^,]+),?~', $str, $m)) {
    $arr1 = array_filter($m[1]);
    if (!$arr2 = array_filter($m[2]))
        unset($arr2);
}
```